# How can I read a special value to string not object with PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I recently use PHP Excel to read data from Excel file. I have a column full of data like "11,12,13,14". It return an object but not the direct data when I use this method below.

```
$currentSheet->getCell($locate)->getValue();
```

Anyone knows how to get the direct value but not an object. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What type of object are you getting returned by the getValue() call?

Under normal circumstances, the only possible object return would be a PHPExcel_RichText object if the cell contained rich text. This does have a magic __toString() method, or you can use the getPlainText() to retrieve the content of that richtext object as a simple PHP string value.